# Derivative of a bounded function

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering for the bounded function $b(t)$ what statements can be made about the derivative of

$f(t)=exp(b(t))$

specifically it would be nice if the derivative $f'$ were bounded.

Comment: Are you assuming $b$ is also differentiable?

Comment: no, just bounded unfortunately.  Is there anything I can assume since b(t) is bounded => f(t) is bounded => f' can only be unbounded for limited periods

Comment: See the example I gave in a comment to marty's answer. Nothing about boundedness implies differentiability. Therein lies your problem.

Comment: thanks everyone email from the prof says i can chose b, so this is trivial

Answer (score 1):

Only if $b'(t)$ is bounded, since $f'(t) = b'(t) exp(b(t))$.

Try $b(t) = sin(t^2)$.

Comment: I was thinking: Try $b(t) = \log(1 + \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(t))$.